# How to preserve export{my_function} in the output when using the Google closure compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I have a simple task. The input is like this:

```
function my_function()
{
}
export {my_function};
```

I want to preserve the line in the output:

```
export {my_function};
```

The motivation is to use the output in my script later.

```
<javascript type="module">
    import {my_function} from 'my_compiled.js';
</javascript>
```

I tried many options, but the output file does not have the "export" statement in it. Could you please help me achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: If it’s only one, export you need added to the end of a built file, you could use the “output wrapper” setting to append the export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Closure Compiler docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export), you should set your exports on global object:

```
function my_function()
{
}

window["my_function"] = my_function;

export {my_function};
```

And later:

```
<javascript type="module">
    var my_function = window.my_function;
</javascript>
```

Note that you need to use array accessor when setting export on global object, so that Closure Compiler does not rename it: `window["my_function"] = ..`

Comment: Running this through the latest Closure compiler still removes the export statement though.